# XSS potential in a JavaScript variable assignment

Tags: javascript, security, xss

**Background**
I'm trying to better understand potential XSS attack scenarios. I understand if you are retrieving data component 'unknow_data' from a server and not validating it the following scenarios could allow malicious code to run.

```
<script src = unknow_data >
```

or

```
<a href=unknow_data></a>
```

Where `unknow_data` could be 'javascript:somethingMalicious' instead of pure data.

**Question**

Is there any threat of XSS when passing unknown data directly into a JavaScript object and not a script tag or html attribute? For example:

```
var G = unknow_data;
```

What javascript code, if any, would have to be injected into a plain javascript object for it to be a security risk? My thinking so far is that this is only a threat if you are calling

```
eval(G)
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

It would definitely be a security hole.

Example, the `unknown_data` could be `1; alert('xss')`.

However, if you JSON encoded it using your server-side language, it would be safe to print it there (however it may have encoded attacks in it - deal with it like you normally would depending on its context).

Comment: Yea I'm using an Owasp library to encode the data on the server. Unknown_data is actually property of the json response coming from the server. I encoded each property server-side before encoding everything into JSON and passing it to the browser. Assuming I never call eval() on any parts of the JSON response on the browser, if unknown_data was "1; alert('xss")" wouldn't it never be executed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you do with `G`.

Certainly `eval`-ing it would be problematic, but why would you do that anyway?

In addition to the attack mentioned by @alex, if you insert in into the DOM in one way or another, then that's another attack surface.
You should HTML-escape it before inserting it into the DOM, either on the server or the client. If you are using a templating language like Handlebars, then `{{G}}` will take care of the HTML escaping for you. You need to be cautious with the triple-mustache (`{{{G}}}`), which skips the HTML escaping.